# Looping without creating new variables for Scanners?

Tags: java

I am in need of help in an assessment I have to submit. our assessment is to make a mini cashier like a program that inputs ID and Quantity by however much I want to put. I'm still new.

```java
int item, itm_id, ctr = 1, itm_qtty;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a Number of Items: ");
item = input.nextInt();

do {
    System.out.println("Item ID: ");
    itm_id = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Item Quantity: ");
    itm_qtty = input.nextInt();
    ctr++;
} while (ctr <= item);

System.out.println("Item ID  |  Item Quantity");
System.out.println(itm_id + "      |  " + itm_qtty);
```

What I want is to input the number of items I want to input > and I per se input 3 then a loop starts and makes me input the Item's ID and Quantity 3 times.

but here's the catch in my system, every time another loop comes it overwrites the variable's previous input.

Here's an example of the output that I want:
Enter a Number of Items: *3*

```
(1st loop)
Item ID: *54628*
Item Quantity: *2*
(a loop occurs)

(2nd loop)
Item ID: *45462*
Item Quantity: *1*
(another loop occurs)

(3rd loop)
Item ID: *97832*
Item Quantity: *3*
```

It would print out:

```
Item ID. . . . . . . .Item Quantity
54628. . . . . . . . .2
45462. . . . . . . . .1
97832. . . . . . . . .3
```

Comment: You should store the results in a list/array/some other collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean kind of this? i hope right.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    // Get Number of Item
    System.out.print("Enter a Number of Items: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int itemNum = sc.nextInt();

    // Gathering Data
    int[] itemIdArr = new int[itemNum];
    int[] itemQuantityArr = new int[itemNum];
    for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
        System.out.println("Item ID: ");
        itemIdArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Item Quantity: ");
        itemQuantityArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.close();

    // Print Data
    System.out.println("Item ID / Item Quantity");
    for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
        System.out.println(itemIdArr[i]+" / "+itemQuantityArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for a very good solution I've never thought about using array list since it wasn't tackled in our discussions as of now. I've thought about making a user-defined method never really thought of it as a solution. So I'm very thankful this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of the variables every time you assign them to a new
input.
so when you print the value at the end of the run you are printing the last value that was assigned.
you need to either print the value after each iteration (before re-assigning the variable) or store the values in an array/list.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int item, itm_id, ctr = 1, itm_qtty;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a Number of Items: ");
    item = input.nextInt();
    int [] item_ids = new int[item];
    int [] item_quntities = new int[item];
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Item ID: ");
        itm_id = input.nextInt();
        item_ids[ctr - 1] = itm_id;
        System.out.println("Item Quantity: ");
        itm_qtty = input.nextInt();
        item_quntities[ctr - 1] = itm_qtty;
        ctr++;
    } while (ctr <= item);

    System.out.println("Item ID  |  Item Quantity");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < item ; i ++) {
        System.out.println(item_ids[i]+ "   |  " + item_quntities[i]);
    }
}
```